# How does Scala know what method to invoke ( named parameters )

Tags: scala, named-parameters

```
class Algo { 
    def a(  a : String = "Hola ",  b : String  = "adios" ) {
        print( a )
        print( b )
    }
    def a() { 
        print ("Uh?")
    }
}
object Algo { 
    def main( args : Array[String] ) { 
        new Algo().a()
    }
}
```

prints `Uh?`

If method `a()` is not defined, the code prints "Hola adios" using the default values.

So, I deduce, from this, that, if an exact signature is match, that is preffered.

Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This behavior is clearly defined in [SID #1](http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/1), section 3.1.

> **Overloading Resolution** In a method application expression, when multiple overloaded
>   alternatives are applicable, the alternative which use default arguments
>   is never selected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Only if no fitting signature is found are default parameters used.

See [this talk](http://days2010.scala-lang.org/node/138/147), some guy asks exactly for this.